# JGit TreeFilters behaving unexpectedly

Tags: jgit

I have been trying to use JGits's TreeFilters to obtain all files with a specific suffix except for one specific file. However, the filters do not work as I would expect. Can someone please explain? (I know that implementing my own TreeFilter as a workaround is easy.)

```
PathSuffixFilter.create(".xml");
```

Result (as expected): All files with suffix .xml.

```
PathFilter.create("dir/sub-dir/pom.xml")
```

Result (as expected): dir/sub-dir/pom.xml

```
PathFilter.create("dir/sub-dir/pom.xml").negate()
```

Result (as expected): All files except dir/sub-dir/pom.xml

So I combined these filters with AndTreeFilter in order to obtain my desired result:

```
AndTreeFilter.create(
    PathSuffixFilter.create(".xml"),
    PathFilter.create("dir/sub-dir/pom.xml").negate()
);
```

Expected result: All files with suffix .xml except dir/sub-dir/pom.xml

Actual result: All files with suffix .xml that are not in dir.

So I further investigated:

```
AndTreeFilter.create(
    PathSuffixFilter.create(".xml"),
    PathFilter.create("dir/sub-dir/pom.xml")
);
```

Result (as expected): dir/sub-dir/pom.xml

```
AndTreeFilter.create(
    PathSuffixFilter.create(".xml"),
    PathFilter.create("dir/sub-dir/NOT_EXISTING.xml")
);
```

Result (as expected): Empty

```
AndTreeFilter.create(
    PathSuffixFilter.create(".xml"),
    PathFilter.create("dir/sub-dir/NOT_EXISTING.xml").negate()
);
```

Expected result: All files with suffix .xml

Actual result: All files with suffix .xml that are not in dir.

```
AndTreeFilter.create(
    PathSuffixFilter.create(".xml"),
    PathFilter.create("NOT_EXISTING/sub-dir/pom.xml").negate()
);
```

Result (as expected): All files with suffix .xml.